# protected 'sandbox' control for web designers and web developers

Tags: php, html, ruby

I am setting up my new dedicated box and have decided to go with something a bit more elegant to host project files for client viewing before launch. However, right now, I have them sitting in a public directory with no styling or protection.

Is there a 'sandbox' or project control that has a UI and is password protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHPfileNavigator](http://pfn.sourceforge.net/) is a login-based file browser. You can see a demo [here](http://www.litoweb.net/pfn2/).